# How to pass a value from a normal PhoneApplication page to a ChildWindow page in Wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How to pass a values form a normal page(MainPage.xaml) which is a  PhoneApplication page to ChildWindow page(which is silverlight control) ?

The below syntax used to pass values normally is not working:

In Mainpage.xaml:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Xy.xaml?message=" + Message, UriKind.Relative));
```

In Xy.xaml :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("message"))
    {
                   //do this
    }
}
```

Here the NavigationContext is not working !!

Is there an option to read the values in the Childwindow page ??

Comment: It may help if you can explain what you mean by "ChildWindow" as WP7 doesn't support `ChildWindow` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I have used the ChildWindow from the Silverlight.The xaml starts with <tk:ChildWindow></tk:ChildWindow>

Comment: The below link solves this question : http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/Silverlight/Pass-Data-from-Parent-window-to-ChildWindow.aspx Thanks